# Derivative of inner product (taking limit inside)

Tags: derivatives, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

For each $x \in [a,b]$ let $A_x: H \to H$ be an operator on a Hilbert space.

The inner product $(A_xu,v)_{H}$ can be thought of as a function from $[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}.$ I want to say that $(A_xu,v)_{H}$ is differentiable in the classical sense
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(A_{x+h}u,v)_{H}-(A_xu,v)_{H}}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(A_{x+h}u-A_xu,v)_{H}}{h}=(\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{A_{x+h}u-A_xu}{h},v)_{H}=0$$

Does it make sense to write the above? In what sense then is the limit on the RHS (the one inside the inner product) taken??

Comment: You can't move the $h$ you divide by outside the limit. You'd get $$\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{A_{x+h}u-A_xu}{h}, v\right)_H,$$ but whether that limit exists when the limit of inner products exists is a question that needs to be answered.

Comment: Oops, yes that's what I meant to write.

Comment: But surely if the LHS limit exists so does the RHS since we are just doing simple rearranging using continuity.

Comment: It's not so simple. If $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} q_h$ exists, then certainly $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} (q_h,v)_H$ exists for all $v\in H$. But from the existence of $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} (q_h,v)_H$ for some fixed $v \in H$, you absolutely cannot conclude the convergence of $q_h$, and if $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} (q_h,v)_H$ exists for all $v \in H$, then you still only have a weak limit, not a strong one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example to show that the existence of $$ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(A_{x+h}u - A_xu,v)_{H}}{h}$$ for  all $u,v$ does not imply the existence of $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{A_{x+h}u-A_xu}{h}$$

The space $H$ will be $L^2[-1,1]$. Let $A_x=0$ for $x\le 0$, and $A_x f(t)=x \exp ( it/{x}) f(t)$ for $x>0$. For any $u,v \in H$ we have 
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(A_{ h}u - A_0 u,v)_{H}}{h}
 = \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-1}^1 \exp ( it/{h}) u(t)v(t)\,dt =0 
$$
by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. On the other hand, 
$$
\frac{ A_{ h}u-A_0 u }{h }(t) = \exp ( it/{h}) u(t)  
$$
is a unimodular multiple of $u$, so it does not converge to $0$ (nor to anything else) as $h\to 0$, unless $u=0$.

Recommended reading: [Weak operator topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology).